# how to create separate blade for menu , content , sidebar and footer

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

my html code is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

master.blade.php is

```
<html>
    <head>
    @yield('title')
    @yield('css')
@yield('js')
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

menu.blade.php is

```
<div id="menu"></div>
```

sidebar.blade.php is

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

footer.blade.php is

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

my view file is home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
<title>:: Login ::</title>
@stop
@section('js')
@stop
@extends('layouts.menu')    
@extends('layouts.sidebar')    
@extends('layouts.footer')
```

router.php

```
Route::get('home', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home'));
```

HomeController.php is

```
public function home()
    {
        return View::make('home');
    }
```

id i run

```
localhost/project/public/index.php/home
```

it shows only master blade file content , y sidebar , footer and menu not showing , what is the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a your layout `@including` your menu:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        @yield('css')
        @yield('js')
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="container">
            @include('menu')
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Item 1
        </li>
        <li>
            Item 2
        </li>
        <li>
            Item 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And your view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    :: Login ::
@stop

@section('content')
    This is your content!
@stop
```

Comment: wats the difference between '@extends' and '@include'

Comment: @extends is, basically, for layouts so if you're not using it as the first item of your view, it will not work. If you need to add some more code to some of your views, you have to use section or include, depending on the case.